# Take value from URL and use it in select

Tags: c#, sql, select

Trying to take a value in the header, and if it already there is a value in the DB with those parameters, then, do not show anything in the form. In the theory, it should be working, but all I am getting is no value change. IE (0 and not 1 or 2).

I am gathering all the correct values, but I am not getting the value to be changed. In my DB, there is already a row with those parameters...

```
public int checkRef(int id, int numRef)
        {
            int chk = 0;
            base.Db.Open();
            string cuerito = "select count(*) from [JobApplication].[dbo].[tbl_references] where [userId] = @idUser and [numRef]=@testRef";
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(cuerito, base.Db);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idUser",id);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@testRef",numRef);
            chk = (int)command.ExecuteScalar();
            if (chk > 0)
            {
                chk = 1;
            }
            else
                chk = 2;
            return chk;
        }

protected void getCandidate()
    {
        string idCandi = Request.QueryString["id"];
        string numRef = Request.QueryString["ref"];
        ASF.HC.JobApplication.BO.Referencia refo = new ASF.HC.JobApplication.BO.Referencia();
        int numReferenciado = 0;
        int bandera = 0;
        try
        {
            numReferenciado = refo.checkRef(Int32.Parse(idCandi), Int32.Parse(numRef));
        } catch(Exception ae)
        {

        };
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(numRef) || numReferenciado == 2)
        {
            bandera =6;
        }
        else
        {
            bandera = Int32.Parse(numRef);
        }
        if(bandera<0 || bandera > 3)
        {
            tblGetInfo.Visible = false;
            tblThanks.Visible = true;
        }
        ASF.HC.JobApplication.BO.User dbUsuarios = new ASF.HC.JobApplication.BO.User();
        int idNum;
        if(idCandi == null)
        {
            idNum = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            idNum = int.Parse(idCandi);
        }
        String fname= dbUsuarios.GetById(idNum).FirstName +" "+ dbUsuarios.GetById(idNum).LastName;
        idCand.Text = fname;
        idCand.ReadOnly = true;
        candi.Text = numReferenciado.ToString();//here I validate the value..

    }
```

Comment: Your question is not clear enough but make sure that you don't want to use `&&` operator instead of `||` here `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(numRef) || numReferenciado == 2)`

Comment: Thing is, numReferenciado is not to changing to either 1 or 2, as supposed in method checkRef(). It stays the same, as 0. Although in the select, it should return 1 row and change the value of numReferenciado to 1, to check all the validations. There must be something wrong in the method checkRef, but can't really get what....

Comment: Shouldn't you close your `SqlConnection` also? `Db.Close();`

Comment: Well yeah, that also needed to be done :P. But that does not change any value :(

Comment: Where in your code are you testing the value of `chk`?

Comment: candi.Text = numReferenciado.toString()... This way, whenever the page loads (it takes the value from the URL) and makes the call and fills up a asp:Label with the value.